# Is there an easy way to collapse multiple rows with the same unique identifier into one row using numpy/ pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe for loans, which looks like this:

[Loan Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMkNE.png)

My goal is to have only one row per loan ID, instead of multiple rows. I want to have separate columns for the age of co-borrowers and main borrower. I know that the maximum number of co-borrowers, so I know the number of columns to create.

[Desired data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADz9G.png)

I wrote a script to achieve this, however, it takes about 6 minutes to run on a dataframe with 30K rows. Is there a faster way to do this? Below is a snippet of my code:

```
loan_id = []
idx = 0
col_count = 0
idx_col = 0

# first, sort the dataframe to make sure same loan numbers are together
co_ap.sort_values(by = ['Loan No.'], inplace = True)

for loan in laon['Loan ID'].items():
    if loan[1] not in loan_id:
        loan_id.append(loan[1])
        col_count = 0
        idx_col = idx 
    if loan['Borroer'][idx] != 'Main':
        col_count += 1
# update desired column
        loan['ST_Age_coap_' + str(col_count)][idx_col] = loan['Age'][idx]
    else:
        loan['ST_Age_main'][idx_col] = loan['Age'][idx]

# if the idx_col != idx, that means we are operating on a row, which we eventually have to drop,
# input a dummy value in any column, which will act as an identifier later on to know which rows to drop
    if idx_col != idx:
        loan['ST_Age_main'][idx] = -1
        
    idx += 1

# drop rows not required    
co_ap = co_ap[co_ap['ST_Age_main'] != -1]
```

Comment: Please, avoid using images as sample code, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do `groupby` with `cumcount` and apply `pivot_table`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Loan ID':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'],'Borrower':['co','co','main','main','co','main','co','co'],'age':[23,24,27,27,45,34,33,23]})
df['temp']=df.groupby([df['Loan ID'],df['Borrower']]).cumcount().astype(str)
df['temp']=np.where(df['Borrower']=='main','',df['temp'])
df_new=df.pivot_table(index='Loan ID',columns=df['Borrower']+df['temp'],values='age',aggfunc=sum)
df_new.columns=[i+ ' Age' for i in df_new.columns]
df_new=df_new.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `pivot` is likely what you're looking for.

```py
df.pivot(index='Loan ID', columns='Borrower', values='Age')
```